# Sending (*) as an option in USSD string

Tags: android, gsm, ussd

Lately i know that we can run USSD with multiple options in a single call like this:

```
I want to call (*3040#), then i want to choose the first option, then the second one,
so i can use (*3040*1*2#) instead of calling USSD multiple times
```

But there's an option which is (*) in the USSD menu options.

like this:

```
1. first option
2. second option 
*. more
```

how can i choose this option without calling USSD multiple times

i am tried to use different way to insert options like:

```
  *3040# , 1 , 2
```

But it doesn't work for me.

if you don't know the answer, do you have another way to deal with USSD codes with multiple inputs using android system.